# How to determine the current section in a UITableView from a button press in the header

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a `button` that is in a table `header view` and need the action to be able to determine in which `section` button is pressed (which header)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 28))
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
    button.setTitle("+", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GLAccountTableViewController.buttonTouched), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)        
    return view
}
```

Is there a way to identify which section button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need somehow to trigger the button click in headerView.

You can add a tag refer to the section when creating the button

```
button.tag = section
```

Then in your onclick function you know in which section the button was pressed.